# Docker container writing to host rsyslog server using localhost

Tags: docker, redhat

I have a docker container called `A` that runs on `Server B`. `Server B` is running rsyslog server.
I have a script running on A that generates logs, and these logs are sent via a python facility that forwards these logs to either a SIEM or a syslog server.
I would like to send this data to port 514 on `Server B` so that rsyslog server can receive it.
I can do this if I specify the servername in the python script as `serverB.fqdn` however it doesnt work when I tried to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

I assume this is expected behaviour because I guess container A refers to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as itself, hence failing to send. Is there a way for me to send logs to `Server B` that it sits on without having to go over the network (which I assume it does when it connects to the fqdn) so the network overhead can be reduced?

Thanks J

Comment: Is the network overhead an actual problem you're experiencing? I would say it isn't, because I'm running away bigger systems than you describe and it isn't. I would say keep it pragmatic, forget the negligible overhead. I would rather move the syslog to a container than waste time on the overhead thing. Also FQDN or IP both use the network, the first uses an aditional cacheable DNS query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Unix socket for this.

Here's an article on how to [Use Unix sockets with Docker](https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Feb/15/docker-unix-socket/)